# How to patch a chained function with different return value with unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, apache-spark, python-unittest

I have a function that looks like this:

```
def my_function():
   sql_output = spark.sql('query').select('value').collect()[0]['value']
```

And I'm trying to use Mock and Patch in Unittest to patch the variable `sql_output`. And I'm patching the `spark.sql` function:

```
@patch("my_function.spark.sql")
def test_my_function(self, mock_sql_functions):
    from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
    from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

    mock_sql_functions.return_value.select.return_value.collect.return_value = None
```

And my goal is to set `sql_output` equal to None. But I'm not able to do so, because the return value is None, but `my_function` tries to get `[0]['value']` on the `None` value.

I tried making the return value as a dataframe such as this:

```
sdf = spark.createDataFrame([('None', 'None', 'None')], ['value', 'value2', 'value3'])
sdf = sdf.withColumn("value", lit(None).cast(StringType()))

mock_sql_functions.return_value.select.return_value.collect.return_value = sdf
```

But it does not work, because I need to use `[0]['value']`, at the same time of `collect()` I believe.
So my question is, how can I set those multiple `return_value` to different values? Or how can I set `sql_output` value as `None` in the `unittest`?

Comment: Is `my_function` also the name of your module? Because the patch decorator usually looks like `@patch("module.object")`, whereas it looks like you're treating `spark.sql` as a member of `my_function` when its actually a separate module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least-invasive way to solve this with your current code would be to use something like this:

```py
import pyspark.sql

class SomethingTest(unittest.TestCase):

  @mock.patch.object(pyspark.sql, 'SparkSession')
  def test_my_function(self, mock_session):
    mock_session.sql.return_value.select.return_value.collect.return_value = [
        {'value': None},
    ]
    # This is the same value that thebadgateway's answer suggests.

    # the rest of your test
```

However, it is usually better to be less invasive in mock testing. Is there a simple `DataFrame` you can construct, that you can use for the return value of `SparkSession.sql`? That way, you can also ensure that your `.select()` and `.collect()` rounds are doing what you expect them to.

This would look something like:

```py
  @mock.patch.object(pyspark.sql, 'SparkSession')
  def test_my_function(self, mock_session):
    my_dataframe = pyspark.sql.DataFrame(...)  # build your frame
    mock_session.sql.return_value = my_dataframe

    # the rest of your test
```

And while this is not directly in response to your specific problem, it's usually a better idea to use `mock.patch.object`, since that lets you directly reference the object you're trying to patch, rather than relying on searching for it by name as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I see what is meant now. Maybe try to patch with a test class like this:

```
class TestSpark:
    def sql(self, arg): pass
    def select(self, arg): pass
    def collect(self): return [{"value": None}]
```

Then the decorator would be something like `@mock.patch.object(the_module, "spark", return_value=TestSpark())`